# What's meaning of "get to the meat of"?

Tags: phrases, idioms

For example, "let's get to the meat of the problem"?

When could I use this phrase?

Does this mean "let's get to the most important part of the problem"?

Comment: I've edited your question.  We don't say *let's getting*, rather we would say *let's get*.  And, you can say get *into* the meat, but usually people say let's get *to*.

Comment: Also, let me suggest that you might be better served by our sister site, the English Language Learners site.

Comment: I tried to Google the question (figured it's been answered before, I was wrong). Despite only being an hour old, [it's at the top of the Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22meat+of+the+problem%22+expression).

Comment: I think "the heart of" is a a more common idiom for this, but it could be a regional difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, "the meat of it" means the most important part of the problem just as it means the most important part of the meal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're eating a sandwich, you might even consider throwing away the bread (at least nowadays, given concerns over "carbs.")

That's so that you can get "to the meat" of it, i.e., the good part.